# How can I add relationships to the aspnetdb database in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to use the Memberships in MVC. I know there is the built in ASPNETDB database which has all the basic tables for users and such. But what if I wanted to add a relationship between one of my custom tables and this built in user table?

If I had a database table that contained blog comments, we'll call it Comment. And each Comment had a userID associated with it could I do something like?

User.Comments.Add(someCommentObj)

Anyone know of a good article on this? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this extensive article on the MembershipProvider:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Look at Part 6 and 7, you'll probably want to implement a custom ProfileProvider and store the comment reference in the Profile.

> **Part 6** - capture additional user-specific information using the
> Profile system. Learn about the
> built-in SqlProfileProvider.
>
> **Part 7** - the Membership, Roles, and Profile systems are all build using
> the provider model, which allows for
> their implementations to be highly

Comment: If I'm using linq to entities can these relationships be created automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a fully automatic way. Search for "linq to entities profileprovider". E.g.: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LINQCustomProfileProvider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own custom membership tables then you'll need to build your own MembershipProvider. Matt Wrock has a [walkthrough](http://mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx):

You'll notice that the default AccountModel allows you to inject your own provider:

```
public AccountMembershipService(MembershipProvider provider)
{
    _provider = provider ?? Membership.Provider;
}
```

Nerdinner has an example of [dependency injection](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2009/03/12/applying-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-com-application.aspx) that you would probably find useful:

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** Here are two solutions that will work. The first one is easy. The 2nd one, I think is what you're after, but take it for what it's worth. Make sure you realize what you're doing, since this will take the membership provider data and access it directly, which could result in some hidden bombs if you're not careful (like deleting data).

The membership data is meant to just be used for authenticating; roles for authorizing; profiles for user speicific data (like time zone or favorite color.

***Solution One***

If you wanted to add a comment under the current user (or any user) you could do:

```
var comment = new Comment(....);
comment.userId = User.Identity.Name; //for user name
```

or

```
comment.userId = new Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey); //for guid in table
```

That's the eays way and you never really have direct access to the aspnet tables, you just use its info.

***Solution Two***

I'm assuming that you're using L2S and the designer in VS.

By adding the membership table(s) to your L2S design, you will get access to its data. This may even be preferable for some quick querying (like dates, lock out info, etc. since you don't have to use the built-in sprocs which have some serious over-kill and heavy code). If you create a relationship in the DB or in the L2S designer, you'll have a relationship that you can access like your question asks.

At this point, the designer has created your classes for comments and users. If you do anything with the actual user table you just created, you're circumventing the membership provider's design - don't do this unless you now what you're doing. When you add a comment to the User, it will add the comment to the comments tables with the correct relationship intact.

You should now be able to do:

```
var user = MyUser.GetById(userId);
user.Comments.Add(comment);
```

Remember, that the User in this case is different than when you do

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userId);
```